# Tooltip appears over the element in intro.js mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css, intro.js

I am using intro.js for an initial tour of a page on my website. The tour looks good on Desktop but on mobile, the tool-tip appears right above the element it is describing. The user cannot see the element in mobile view as tool-tip appears right above the element. See image below:

[image]

I tried customizing the postitions of tool-tip but the output remains the same. The script that I used to customize the position is given:

```
var tour = introJs();
tour.setOption('positionPrecedence', ['top', 'bottom', 'left', 'right']);
```

Also, I cannot see the numbers of data-steps above tool-tip. No such problem exists on Desktop version.

Can someone please explain what the issue is? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Together, the following CSS helped me solve the issue:

```
@media (max-width: 500px) { 
    .introjs-helperNumberLayer{
        left: 0px!important;
        top: -10px!important;
    }
    .introjs-tooltip{
        margin-top: 40px!important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The source code for the 2.5.0 version states:

```
/* Precedence of positions, when auto is enabled */
positionPrecedence: ["bottom", "top", "right", "left"]
```

If you want your customization to work try setting in each step item the 
**position** field to **auto** as the default position is set to **bottom**.

e.g:

```
tour.setOption('steps', [
    {
      intro: '...'
      position: 'auto'
    }
])

tour.setOption('positionPrecedence', ['top', 'bottom', 'left', 'right'])
```

Also try to set the **element** property which takes the first element from the document on the given selector.