# How can i use intro.js on mobile devices appropriately

Tags: javascript, css, intro.js

Description
When using introjs on mobile devices with screen width under 600px, the tooltip will cover the element. when i hold the device horizontally, the tooltip moves into position. i have tried to set a custom css for the tooltip but when the screen is under 600px the css rules i set break and the element centers itself and the tooltip centers above the element.

Expected Behavior
tooltip to display under element, where i set in the intructions.

i have even added a topmargin of 50px to the tooltip in a custom css file. this only moves the element away when the screen is wide. otherwise, it covers the element

Actual Behavior
tooltip covers element

Errors and Screenshots (optional)
no errors are provided in the console.

[screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BREGE.png)

this video demonstrates the issue
https://youtu.be/ptFB5ZrL8ks

more detail:

this has been mentioned [here before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47472439/tooltip-appears-over-the-element-in-intro-js-mobile-view)

I have added a margin to `.introjs-tooltip{}` in [this](https://dd7tel2830j4w.cloudfront.net/f1612223340850x692571508635542000/introjs.css) custom css file however the margin is only present when the body of the window is greater than ~600px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to update my css and JS to 3. i was unknowingly using an older version.

Thank you all.